Why does an update to docker.io require a system reboot?
I recently got a notification to restart my laptop due to some updates.  Since I always check to see what caused the reboot and today I was surprised to find this:
$ > cat /var/run/reboot-required /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs 
*** System restart required ***
docker.io

Why would a system restart be required for a docker.io update?  Wouldn't restarting the containers suffice?
Any ideas before I restart?
UPDATE 1:
The changelog for docker.io has this:
docker.io-app (26.1.3-0ubuntu1~24.04.1) noble; urgency=medium

  * Backport from oracular to noble. (LP: #2040461)
    - d/t/docker-in-lxd: workaround Apparmor/kernel bug. (LP #2067900)
    - Update AppArmor template to allow confined runc to kill containers
      (LP: #2065423).
      + d/docker.io.postinst: notify that a reboot is required to apply the
        fix (the AppArmor profile need to be reloaded).

 -- Athos Ribeiro <athos.ribeiro@canonical.com>  Mon, 14 Oct 2024 11:29:26 -0300

To me, the postinst process should have restarted apparmor instead of requiring a reboot.  Is my thinking flawed?

There's a Launchpad bug report number given in the changelog entry, did you check that? In particular, point c in comment #18.

@muru - Thanks.  I missed that. They should have added that in the parenthesized section - as in (the AppArmor profile need to be reloaded - see comment 18 @ LP 2065423 as to why a reboot is required).  In any case, please re-post this as the answer and I'll accept.  Cheers.

See point c in comment #18 of the Launchpad bug mentioned in the changelog for the rationale:

c) Just like with libpod/golang-github-containers-common[1], just applying the docker.io-app update won't fix the system, because the apparmor profile is named just "docker-default", and when starting a new container it checks if a profile with that name is already loaded or not, regardless if it changed or not. We will be shipping a fixed profile, but since it's still named docker-default, it won't be loaded. Here, however, we checked the code and the name "docker-default" is hardcoded in a few places, so adding a version suffix would require more changes and some extra testing. Given how this bug is high priority, I suggest:

recommend a reboot in postinst
file an issue upstream, describing the problem and suggesting the same approach as podman/golang-github-containers-common has taken, by versioning the apparmor profile name.


